# list comprehension for multiple variables generate month name and number

Tags: python, list, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I am trying to generate a list of the format "name and a serial number".
For example: `month name + number`

```
print [each, i for i, each in enumerate(calendar.month_name[1:])]
```

Obviously am not able to print both each and i variables.
Is there a better way to about this?
Thanks!

Comment: How about `print [(each, i) for i, each in enumerate(calendar.month_name[1:])]`

Comment: Sweet! guess having tuples will also do. Thanks!

Comment: Have added it as an answer, Thank you

Comment: should the month not start at 1?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham So you mean to say `enumerate(... , start = 1)`

Comment: @BhargavRao, yes unless the OP wants jan to be 0 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert them to tuples and print them

```
print [(each, i) for i, each in enumerate(calendar.month_name[1:])]
```

Or as Padraic [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891044/list-comprehension-for-multiple-variables-generate-month-name-and-number/27891124#comment44183129_27891044), you can start from `1` as

```
print [(each, i) for i, each in enumerate(calendar.month_name[1:],start = 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can zip if you want functional:

```
print(zip(*(calendar.month_name[1:],xrange(1,13))))
[('January', 1), ('February', 2), ('March', 3), ('April', 4), ('May', 5), ('June', 6), ('July', 7), ('August', 8), ('September', 9), ('October', 10), ('November', 11), ('December', 12)]
```

Comment: I guess the advantage with enumerate is that it would generate a number as long as it found calendar.month_name.next(). This is the reason I didn't want to "limit" the code by using xrange. Thanks though :)

Comment: Unless they remove or add a month to the calender we should be ok ; )anyway enumerate will always start at 0 unless you specify so this will behave exactly the same.

Comment: Oh no i mean that here calendar name is one instance of my usage. I just needed something that would spew out strings. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
for i, each in enumerate(calendar.month_name[1:]):
    print each, i    # this will print on variables per line
```

this will print list:

```
print [[each, i] for i, each in enumerate(calendar.month_name[1:])]
```

Comment: I particularly wanted a one liner. Thanks though.

Comment: @sindhus second one is one liner